# presort data for balanced quadtree

Tags: java, sorting, computational-geometry, quadtree

The PMR Rectangle Quadtree is a quadtree which has an list of (Rectangle) objects in each leaf. This is called a bucket.

The structure of this quadtree is dependent on the order of inserting the elements.
The inventor of that quadtree proposed to achieve a balanced quadtree for data that are in advance known (static), that way that the (rectangles) objects to be inserted should be pre-sorted by x and y coordinates.

**What exactly is meant by sorting by x and y coordinates to achieve a balanced quadtree?**

Asume we take the SW corner of the rectangle, Does this mean sort by x and if equal x sort by y? Or doest it mean the first elem is the smallest x, the second the smallest y (independent of  x) ?

The bible for that topic (Hanan Samet: Multidimensional  and Metric Search Structures) does not explain that.

Comment: Any reasons for the downvote, or did you not understand the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a topic where the know how is not really widespread, I have to answer it myself:

The pre sorting order of the elements to be added to the quad tree should be in morton order.  ( see also papers from Hanan Samet)
The morton index calculates an int value from given two (x,y) coordinates, in a way that two coordinates close together also have little difference
 in their morton index.